# Fail after copy-paste an existing project into eclipse

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, hibernate, maven

I am trying to create an eshop and every time I finish something I copy my last project and paste it into the same workspace (I am working in Eclipse with Maven, hibernate, MySQL).

Today, I have 2 problems and I would like your help. My last project is named eMusicStore35. I cannot run this project because I have not finish all the methods I design.

I finish them in the next project named eMusicStore37 (simple copy eMusicStore35 and paste it with name eMusicStore37).

[image]
[image]

As you can see from the images:

1. eMusicStore35 has an exclamation mark (!). This means that I have somewhere in my code error(s)?
2. eMusicStore37 has errors at ApplicationContext.xml and SprignMVC-servlet.xml. When I am going to these files the error is the same:

   ```
   error occurred processing xml 'null'. see error log for more details
   ```

I tried to search a solution for this problem but I did not succeed to solve it.

Let me know if someone wants from me to upload more files to find the errors.

**EDIT**

Second error seems to be solved. I simple do:

**1. Right click on project**

**2. Maven --> update project**

I have tried this **more times** and now it is ok so I cannot understand the previous error.

For the first error I uploaded the next image
[image]

But now, I cannot see any errors in this project.

My xml files are:

**ApplicationContext**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd">

    <!-- Enable autowire -->
    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com" />

    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/myeshop" />
        <property name="username" value="root" />
        <property name="password" value="M@trix2014" />
    </bean>

    <!-- Session Factory Declaration -->
    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.entities" />
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans">true</prop>
                <!-- <prop key="hibernate.default_schema">myeshop</prop> -->
                <prop key="format_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="use_sql_comments">true</prop>


            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="multipartResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
        <property name="maxUploadSize" value="1024000" />
    </bean>

    <security:http auto-config="true">
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/admin/**"
            access="ROLE_USER" />
        <security:form-login login-page="/login"
            default-target-url="/admin/" authentication-failure-url="/login?error"
            username-parameter="username" password-parameter="password" />
        <security:logout logout-success-url="/login?logout" />
    </security:http>

    <security:authentication-manager>
        <security:authentication-provider>
            <security:jdbc-user-service
                data-source-ref="dataSource"
                authorities-by-username-query="SELECT username, authority From authorities WHERE username = ?"
                users-by-username-query="SELECT username, password, enabled FROM users WHERE username = ?" />
        </security:authentication-provider>
    </security:authentication-manager>
</beans>
```

**SpringMVC-servlet**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.2.xsd">


    <!-- My adds-on from previous tutorial -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="com" />
    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <!-- My adds-on from previous tutorial -->

    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/WEB-INF/resources/" />

    <tx:annotation-driven />

</beans>
```

**pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.spring</groupId>
    <artifactId>SpringMVC</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>SpringMVC Maven Webapp</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <java-version>1.7</java-version>
        <org.springframework-version>4.2.6.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- -->

        <!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-context-support -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.36</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.10</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Upload photos -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- This is pre-defined from me!! So comment it!!!!!! -->
        <!-- <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>  maybe error!!! 
        </dependency> -->

        <!-- Validation -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Sping Security Authentication-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- These are for shopping cart! -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.1</version>
        </dependency>






    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>SpringMVC</finalName>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Exclamation mark(!) mostly defines some class path issue. Clean and build using maven.

Comment: I right click on my project, select maven, update project. But nothing changes. What can I do more for this Exclamation mark(!) ?

Comment: *"This means that I have somewhere in my code error(s)?"* What are those errors? Just saying that you have errors is totally useless. If you don't know where to find them, look at the `Problems` view (`Window` > `Show View` > `Problems`).

Comment: I have just edited my post.

Answer (score 0):

From the snipt you shared it shows that problem is not in java code , it is in your xml that's why project shows exclamation mark. You can see in applicationContext.xml and SpringMVC-Servlet.xml having red x mark.

Also you just clone the project by selecting on the project directory and paste it with new name , than you can work in parallel no need to do copy paste every time. Work on which project you want to work.

Comment: Share both xml file content so that can review that and help you to resolve it.

Comment: For exclamation mark : see in problems and Markers views. And if possible share those logs than some one could help you